# Generic Trait Bounds for Vec or Iterables vs Scalars

Tags: generics, rust, traits

Consider the following example:

```rust
use std::str::FromStr;

enum Thing {
    One(String),
    Many(Vec<String>)
}

trait FromThing where Self: Sized {
    fn from_thing(thing: Thing) -> Result<Self, String>;
}

impl<S: FromStr> FromThing for S {
    fn from_thing(thing: Thing) -> Result<Self, String> {
        match thing {
            Thing::One(s) => s.parse().or_else(|_| Err("invalid value".into())),
            _ => Err("expected One, got Many".into())
        }
    }
}

impl<S: FromStr> FromThing for Vec<S> {
    fn from_thing(thing: Thing) -> Result<Self, String> {
        todo!();
    }
}

fn main() {
    let thing = Thing::One("1".into());
    let i: usize = FromThing::from_thing(thing).unwrap();
    println!("{}", i);
}
```

[Playground Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4f517a8b9895f8ffc8bc599b043d8a6e)

If I remove the second impl block, it compiles and runs fine. However, it won't let me define the Vec version because of the possibility of FromStr being implementing on Vec at some point in the future.

The exact error message for search engines:

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `FromThing` for type `std::vec::Vec<_>`
  --> src/main.rs:21:1
   |
12 | impl<S: FromStr> FromThing for S {
   | -------------------------------- first implementation here
...
21 | impl<S: FromStr> FromThing for Vec<S> {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ conflicting implementation for `std::vec::Vec<_>`
   |
   = note: upstream crates may add a new impl of trait `std::str::FromStr` for type `std::vec::Vec<_>` in future versions
```

I can resolve this problem rather simply using nightly `auto_traits` and `negative_impls` but I would  prefer to not use nightly. Is there a constraint I can add to these impls to make them mutually exclusive? If not, is there a solution to this problem in another design pattern or methodology, aside from manually (or via macros) implementing the trait for all scalar types that implement FromStr?

It is okay if the solution only excludes vectors, but it would be best if it could somehow differentiate between Scalars and Collections (or Iterables). But I understand that is unlikely.

Hopefully I'm missing something obvious. :)

Comment: The best thing I can suggest you is to have some newtype wrapper and only impl `FromThing` for it and `Vec`. There is no easy way out of the orphan rules.

Comment: I think you hit the limits of Rust here. Rust desperately needs trait specialization and there already is an [RFC](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/1210-impl-specialization.html) for it, but due to soundness issues there wasn't much progress yet.

Comment: @Finomnis Actually here the OP does not need specialization but the new negative impls (**not** related to the auto traits feature they mentioned, this is related to the orphan rules). But they don't want to use nightly...

Comment: @Finomnis Also it's not obvious at all specialization, if and when lands, will solve the API issues: it may only help performance-related problems. It is very likely that it will be limited to some traits, causing it to be helpless in cases like that.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman got ya.